how to use nthprime command in sed
I want to replace number in text file with  nth prime, I have a executable calculate nth prime, how to use that command in sed to replace every number in front of ## with its nthprime
./nthprime 46

199

sed -e 's/46##/199#/g'

text file includes like these:
(3505948*51##+331)/56439692311
(2608338*52##+401)/2357853732775
(47723079*50##+773)/7419068507
(67##/16##-1)/40446657668663868225798856758

desired output:
(3505948*233#+331)/56439692311
(2608338*239#+401)/2357853732775
(47723079*229#+773)/7419068507
(331#/53#-1)/40446657668663868225798856758


Your example sed command ends up with only one # symbol after the nthprime number, instead of two.  Is that correct?

Are you using the BASH 'factor' command to compute your initial list of primes?

Please add sample input (your text file) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

@SottoVoce  yes, it does

@JeremyBoden, No, I am not

@Cyrus I added some sample lines in first post

You do not want just to replace a number in text file, you want more than that:
(a) You want first to capture the number to be replaced
(b) You then have to pass this number to your script in order nthprime to be calculated
(c) at the end you want to replace the initial number with the output of your external script.
Conclusion: sed is not the tool for this job.

With perl using the nth_prime function of the Math::Prime::Util perl module (in the libmath-prime-util-perl package on Debian and derivatives) to avoid having to fork a process and invoke an external utility for each occurrence of n##:
$ perl -MMath::Prime::Util=nth_prime -pe 's{(\d+)##}{nth_prime($1) . "#"}ge' your-file
(3505948*233#+331)/56439692311
(2608338*239#+401)/2357853732775
(47723079*229#+773)/7419068507
(331#/53#-1)/40446657668663868225798856758

If you do want to invoke your own nthprime utility:
perl -pe 's{(\d+)##}{chomp($res = `nthprime $1`); "$res#"}ge' your-file

Or caching the result as an optimisation to avoid running the command several times for the same prime number:
perl -pe 's{(\d+)#(?=#)}{$cache{$1} //= `nthprime $1` =~ s/\n+\z//r}ge' your-file

Standard sed has no way to run commands. GNU sed does as non-standard extensions with its e command and the e flag to the s command, but those are a security nightmare and also even more inefficient as they also run a shell each time in addition to the command¹, so IMO are best avoided.
One approach with standard utilities would be to generate sh code such as:
cut -c2- << EOF
 (3505948*$(nthprime 51)#+331)/56439692311
 (2608338*$(nthprime 52)#+401)/2357853732775
 (47723079*$(nthprime 50)#+773)/7419068507
 ($(nthprime 67)#/$(nthprime 16)#-1)/40446657668663868225798856758
EOF

To feed to sh, which is almost impossible to do both safely (avoiding command injection vulnerabilities) and portably. The best I can offer:
{
  echo 'cut -c2- << EOF'
  LC_ALL=C sed '
    s/[\\`$]/\\&/g
    s/^/ /
    s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)##/$(nthprime \1)#/g
  ' < your-file
  echo EOF
} | LC_ALL=C sh

That should be safe with GNU sed which can handle non-text. On systems with a different sed implementation, you can make it safer by ensuring the input is valid text by removing the NUL bytes and folding lines that are longer than LINE_MAX (and still make sure we work in the C locale and not the user's where character encoding/decoding could add further complication) with something like:
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  linemax=$(getconf LINE_MAX) || exit
  {
    echo 'cut -c2- << EOF'
    <your-file LC_ALL=C tr -d '\0' |
      fold -w "$(( linemax - 2 ))" |
      sed '
        s/[\\`$]/\\&/g
        s/^/ /
        s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)##/$(nthprime \1)#/g
      '
    echo EOF
  } | sh
)

(untested)

¹ Except on some systems such as Solaris where popen() (which is used by GNU sed's e command/flag) can optimise out the shell invocation when the command is simple enough like perl does with its `cmd` operator.
